# Flash AS3 process GET / POST request?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, get

Why this dont work for me?

all i need is to get `index.php?mykey=123` `mykey` and `123` from url

I only need shortest version of bellow to get above info and put it in text box.

```
var dataSet:String;


var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables("country_id=179");
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
request.url = "http://admin.dev.ts.xxx.com/ajax/ttt_ttt.php";
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = variables;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

try {
    loader.load(request);
} catch (error:Error) {
    trace("Unable to load URL");
}


function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace(event.target.data.welcomeMessage);

    dataSet = loader.data;
    trace(dataSet);
    textbox.text = trace(dataSet);
}
```

i also get some error if i debug

```
[SWF] E:\get_post.swf - 3495 bytes after decompression
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://admin.dev.ts.xxx.com/ajax/ttt_ttt.php
    at get_post_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[get_post_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your URL is incorrect. 
I have had that Stream Error more often. And almost always 
was because of a wrong URL.

Comment: URL certainly wrong atm - get a 404 error at http://admin.dev.ts.xxx.com/ajax/ttt_ttt.php

Comment: That could be because he replaced the real .php file with ttt_ttt.